# Concurrency and ultimate thread group Setup

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I want to use Concurrency thread group, so I'm using this configuration
[image: Configuration CTG]

Why I'm expecting is to send 10 requests in 5 seconds, and hold them for 1 second but the result after running my script is this, more than 10 http request are send.

How can I control only send 10 requests?

Thank you.

[image]

A similar behaviour happens with Ultimate thread group

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending 10 requests in 5 seconds, you're launching 5 threads (virtual users) in 5 seconds, to wit JMeter will add 2 virtual users each second for 5 seconds and then hold the load for 1 second.

The actual number of requests which will be made depends on your application response time, higher response time - less requests, lower response time - more requests.

If you want to send exactly 10 requests in 5 seconds evenly distributed go for the following configuration:

- Normal [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with `users * loops = 10`, to wit:

  - 10 users - 1 loop
  - 5 users - 2 loops
  - etc.
- [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) in `Total Executions` mode and `Throughput` set to `10`

  - HTTP Request

    - [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) configured to send 2 requests per second